# Compare times repesented as string with colon

Tags: c#, time, compare

I have string with colon, for example `"10:28"` and I want to convert this to int variable. I was looking for solution in `System.Globalization.NumberStyles` but I don't find anything. I need that to compare two different times. Maybe is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You really don't want to do this. Instead parse it as a DateTime object and compare the two .TimeOfDay s

Comment: @AustinFrench is right. Take a look [at the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) for what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Str1 = "10:45";
var Str2 = "10:28";

if(TimeSpan.Parse(Str1) > TimeSpan.Parse(Str2) )
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

See [How to: Convert a String to a DateTime (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx)

For example:

```
string time = "11:09";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
```